# SQL System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, sql, ext.net

I wrote a c# function to populate a ext.net store. It works fine in one application, but the same code does not work in another. I am getting a `System.NullReferenceException` on line 26. This is line 26:

```
MyConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Here is my c# function:

```
protected void fillStore(Ext.Net.Store store, string query)
{
    SqlDataReader MyReader;
    SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection();
    MyConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    SqlCommand fillCommand = new SqlCommand();
    fillCommand.CommandText = "select id, name from b2b_group";
    fillCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    fillCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

    fillCommand.Connection.Open();
    MyReader = fillCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    store.DataSource = MyReader;
    store.DataBind();

    fillCommand.Dispose();
    MyConnection.Dispose();
}
```

For simplification, I replaces the query string that would be passed through by a hard-coded one of `"select id, name from b2b_group"`.

I can not seem to figure out why it is giving a `nullReferenceException`, especially seeing as I have the same code working in another project.

I know that there is some little thing I am overseeing, could anyone spot it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Obviously it can't find your connectionstring. Have you verified this in your debugger? Show the value of `MyConnection.ConnectionString`. Show how your XML is defined.

Comment: Well it seems to me that `ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"]` is probably null. Are you sure you added it to the config for this new project?

Comment: That's it! I forgot my connection String -.- I knew I made a stupid mistake...

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I read that, but yes, agreed, it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The connection string  'MyConnectionString' is not present in your configuration file. Check  connectionStrings section.

Comment: I knew I forgot something so simple -.- Thank you!